# A chord Progression question

Tags: chord-progressions

I know that there is lots of chord progression out there that worked and suit many new pop songs. And I know about formulas, but I just came to a chord progression that suits the exact way I want to sing my song in Dm harmonic as below:

Dm Gm C#dim - for first line lyric

Gm C#dim Dm - for second line of my lyric

And these two progression get used for all my song except of a pre chorus that is a bit different.

Is it ok to use it or just stick to formulas?!

Comment: Suite = a large hotel room. Suit = fits well.

Comment: Whoever told you there are “formulas” you should use when writing a song was incorrect. If it sounds good, then it is good. Write exactly what you want.

Comment: @ToddWilcox so Bach's French Suite was written for a large hotel room in France?

Comment: This is a question about an artistic choice, and cannot be answered objectively. If you need inspiration, try learning what chord progressions are used in songs you like, and/or look for theory teaching materials, whatever works the best for you.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I have a suit - same material jacket and trousers, so matches well, but doesn't fit well any more... This is the kind of question my last one hoped would discourage!

Comment: @ToddWilcox - No, Bach's French Suite was written for a Chesterfield & two large wingback chairs ;))